# Command 'db:setup' not recognized"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, dbsetup

When I try the command, I get below output, also there is an error at the bottom saying Error: Command 'db:setup' not recognized:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:108: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:108: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:34: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:108: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:108: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:25: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.15.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:34: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.

Error: Command 'db:setup' not recognized

Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:

generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")

console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")

server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")

dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml

```
         (short-cut alias: "db")
```

new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a

```
         new application called MyApp in "./my_app"
```

In addition to those, there are:

destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")

plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin

runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.